# What happens if matrix $A^2$ has a zero column?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, proof-verification

Let me assume that $A$ is a square matrix and the matrix $A^2$ has a column of zeros. Is it possible for me to prove that A has a column of zeros. I know that the determinants are both zero, however it did not help me. I assumed that jth column is the zero row and had [i,j] term $(a_{i1}*a_{1j}+a_{i2}*a_{2j}+...+a_{ij}*a_{ij}+...+a_{in}*a_{nj}=0)$ equal to zero. I summed it for all $i$ in range 1 and $n$, and tried to prove it. But I was not able to do it. Are there anything I am missing?

Comment: As Misha points out, this claim is not true. It is true, however, that if $A^2$ has a zero column, then $A$ is similar to matrix with a zero column.

Answer (score 11):

Just because $A^2$ has a column of zeroes, doesn't mean $A$ does. For example, $$\begin{bmatrix}1&-1\\1&-1\end{bmatrix}^2=\begin{bmatrix}0&0\\0&0\end{bmatrix}.$$

Comment: Hi @MishaLavrov, this is unrelated to your answer, hence I would be deleting this comment soonest. Please could you help out with this question https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4441875/585488

Answer (score 0):

To obtain other similar couterexamples let consider

$$\begin{bmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{bmatrix}^2=\begin{bmatrix}a^2+bc&ab+cd\\ac+dc&cb+d^2\end{bmatrix}$$

and take for example

- $a^2+bc=0 \implies a=i, b=1, c=1$
- $ac+dc=0 \implies d=-i$

to obtain

$$\begin{bmatrix}i&1\\1&-i\end{bmatrix}^2=\begin{bmatrix}0&0\\0&0\end{bmatrix}$$